# Simplify $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

> How can you simplify $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}}$?

I tried to change $\sqrt8$ to $2\sqrt2$, but I don't know what to do next. Can you simplify it to one layer (square root)?

Comment: Yes, it is $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}}=1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}}=\sqrt{2+1+2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{2}+1)^2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note  that $(1 +\sqrt 2)^2= 1 + 2 + 2\sqrt 2 = 3 + 2\sqrt 2 = 3 + \sqrt 8$.

Hence, $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt 8} = 1 + \sqrt 2$ (the positive square root).

Answer (score 6):

$$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=a+b\sqrt2\iff3+2\sqrt2=a^2+2b^2+2\sqrt2ab.$$So, are there integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+2b^2=3$ and $ab=1$? Yes: $a=b=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Just $$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}}=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt2+2}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt2)^2}=1+\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Try to use the following formula

$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $\sqrt{a^2}=\left|a\right|$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

The first is to use the $(a+b)^2$.

$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{8}} = \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{2}+2} = \sqrt{(1+\sqrt{2})^2} = 1+\sqrt{2}$

The second one is using the following formula: $$\sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}; \;\;\; a \;\;\land\;\;b \ge0, \;\;a^2-b \ge0$$

Using the formula, the following problem can be solved:
$$\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{8}} = \sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{3^2-8}}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{3^2-8}}{2}}$$

$$ \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{8}} = \sqrt{\frac{4}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{2}}$$
$$ \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{8}} = \sqrt{2} \; + 1$$

We can see that our answer is correct and that our formula works. I hope this suits you!